# Get/Set wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl

Tags: php, javascript, theme-customizer

I am trying to get/set the current previewURL within the Customizer.

I enqueue the script with the `customize_controls_print_styles` action:

```
function my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/my-custom-script.js' );
}
add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', 'my_custom_script');
```

In the script I try to set the previewURL and refresh the previewer when the user clicks on a specific customizer section

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    jQuery('#accordion-panel-my-custom-section').click(function(event) {
        // Hard coded URL for testing purposes
        wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl('http://example.com/test/');
        wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
    });

});
```

But it is not working. It only refreshs the previewer, but without changing the previewURL.

If I don't bind the function to a click event it works without problems:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    // Hard coded URL for testing purposes
    wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl('http://example.com/test/');
    wp.customize.previewer.refresh();

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want the sub-method `wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl.set( url );`

Comment: Thanks. But its not working when I try to bind it to a click event. It refresh the previewer but doesn't change the url.

Comment: Actually, it is working. I think there has been a different problem described here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37981